# Do we know a non-trivial example of irrational $\times$ irrational $=$ rational?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

By non trivial I mean something else than $a \times \frac{b}{a}$ and than $\sqrt{a}\times \lambda \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: $xy=q$ implies $y=q/x$, so no "non trivial" example can exist.

Comment: $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2k}}$ and $\frac{1}{\pi^{2k}}$ ?

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi Indeed... I feel stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: @Umberto P. I'm very rusty, but it seems to me those are not irrational numbers?

Comment: @krirkrirk you are right; not enough coffee yet

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I took the first example of triviality to mean that for example, $\pi$ and $\frac{311}{\pi}$ was trivial. If some number not defined using the reciprocal of $\pi$, eg. $e$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant or the Feigenbaum constant, turned out to be $\frac{1112233}{445336\pi}$ this would be a non-trivial example as they are not defined to be rational multiples as $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: use that $$\sqrt[3]{625}\cdot \sqrt[3]{25}$$

Comment: This is "just" a clever way of writing $\sqrt{25} \times \sqrt{25} $" !

Answer (score 2):

$$ (b-\sqrt{a})(b+\sqrt{a}) = b^2-a, $$
perhaps? The two solutions to the quadratic equation with rational coefficients always have rational product: these two numbers are solutions to $x^2-2bx+(b^2-a)=0$.

Comment: Since $$b-\sqrt{a} = \frac{b^2-a}{b+\sqrt{a}},$$ we are in the trivial case after all :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this falls into the category "$x \times \frac{y}{x}$"

Comment: *All examples* will fall in that category

Comment: Yes, they will. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It is still not known whether  $\pi e$ is rational or irrational, so if it was proven that $\pi e$ is rational that could be considered a non-trivial example. In general it's hard to prove irrationality of a number hence it's hard to come up with non trivial examples.

Comment: That's quite a big if.

Comment: @jwg No this is a big $\huge\text{IF}$ (just kidding you're right).

Answer (score 1):

If $$a\times b = r,$$
where $a,b$ are irrational, $r$ is rational,

then one can consider arithmetic mean $m = \dfrac{a+b}{2}$.

According to Vieata's Formulas, there exists quadratic equation
$$x^2-2mx+r=0$$
with solutions $x_1=a, x_2=b$. And these values have form
$$
a = x_1 = m-\sqrt{m^2-r},\\
b = x_2 = m+\sqrt{m^2-r}.
$$

So, you can choose as weird as you wish irrational value $m$, but $a,b$ can be expressed anyway in this simple way via $m$ and $r$ (using radicals).

Examples:

$$
\left(\sqrt[4]{3}-\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\right) \times
\left(\sqrt[4]{3}+\sqrt{\sqrt{3}-1}\right) =1;
$$

$$
\left(\pi-\sqrt{\pi^2-\dfrac{3}{7}}\right) \times
\left(\pi+\sqrt{\pi^2-\dfrac{3}{7}}\right) =\dfrac{3}{7};
$$

$$
\left(2+\sqrt[3]{3}-\sqrt{4\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9}}\right) \times
\left(2+\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt{4\sqrt[3]{3}+\sqrt[3]{9}}\right) =4;
$$

$$\left(\tan(3\pi/7)-\sqrt{\dfrac{2\tan(3\pi/7)}{\tan(\pi/7)}}\right)
\times \left(\tan(3\pi/7)+\sqrt{\dfrac{2\tan(3\pi/7)}{\tan(\pi/7)}}\right)= 1.$$

Hope not all of them are trivial ;)

---

Note: since $m$ was chosen irrational, then both $a,b$ are irrational.

(if both $a,b$ are rational, then their arithmetic mean is rational)

(if one of $a,b$ is rational and other is irrational, then their product cannot be rational)